# TCP over Bluetooth (Windows Sockets)

Tags: windows, network-programming, communication

I need some help with the windows socket programming. I want to make a communication between an android phone (client) and a c++ application (server) with TCP over Bluetooth. On server-side I use windows sockets.

I already established a connection between both instances via RFCOMM but I want to make it over TCP/ IP. Does anyone know how I can create a Bluetooth socket under windows and send TCP messages over it?

Thanks a lot!

%*********** Update *************%

Recently, I tried to implement it via the windows stack. The connection is established but die communication is still rfcomm based. Does anyone know where my error or false thinking is?

```
serverSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);

// error checks

SOCKADDR_BTH sa;
memset (&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
sa.port = 11 & 0xff;
sa.serviceClassId = TCP_PROTOCOL_UUID;
bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&sa, sizeof(sa) );
// error checks

// Register Service
WSAQUERYSET service1;
memset(&service1, 0, sizeof(service1));
service1.dwSize = sizeof(service1);
service1.lpszServiceInstanceName = _T("ViL Data...");
service1.lpszComment = _T("Pushing data to Android");

GUID serviceID1 = TCP_PROTOCOL_UUID; 

service1.lpServiceClassId = &serviceID1;
service1.dwNumberOfCsAddrs = 1;
service1.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;

CSADDR_INFO csAddr1;
memset(&csAddr1, 0, sizeof(csAddr1));
csAddr1.LocalAddr.iSockaddrLength = sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH);
csAddr1.LocalAddr.lpSockaddr = (sockaddr*)&sa;
csAddr1.iSocketType = SOCK_STREAM; 
csAddr1.iProtocol = IPPROTO_TCP;  
service1.lpcsaBuffer = &csAddr1;

WSASetService(&service1, RNRSERVICE_REGISTER, 0)
// error checkings
```

This works all fine and I can connect to the server from my Android app. But I'm still confused why it doesn't transmit it over TCP. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

RFCOMM is an emulated serial port, it has nothing to do with Internet Protocols directly. You'd need to create a transport that runs over RFCOMM, e.g. a PPP connection. On Windows you'd do it by adding a new connection using the network settings from the control panel. The PPP would run over a null modem, essentially. Your application could do it programmatically, to, but it's a whole series of steps. Or, if you don't want to mess with Windows networking stack settings, you could embed a networking stack into your application and have it speak directly using PPP via the RFCOMM port.

Comment: yes I intend to do it with the windows stack and run it of rfcomm but till now I found no solution for that. However, I never thought about creating a PPP from the windows control panel. I'll give it a try - thank you!

Comment: @Lynguistic That's how you're supposed to use bluetooth internet connections: you treat them like a modem that's always connected, and connect as you would with any other typical modem: using PPP.